# Best way to extract all enums from C project

Tags: c, enums

I'm writing my own enums-based backtrace. Basically each function call will append it's error to a pre-defined stack which will eventually include all errors across all function calls.

I want to create an efficient way to parse it. In the end I got `int backtrace[]` with enum values from all over my codebase, and I'd like to relate each enum value to it's name.

This should of course be done post-failure (not at runtime), so what I'm missing is a way, maybe as a part of the compilation step, to dump all my enums and there values to a file. Then i can write a script that parse the errors.

Is there an easy (cross-platform) static tool that does that?

Comment: @user3386109 enum values (for errors) are unique, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you log the errors, but how about:

```c
typedef enum
{
  E_SUCCESS = 0,
  E_FAIL,
...
} error_t;

typedef struct
{
  error_t code;
  char * error_name;
} backtrace_entry_t;

backtrace_entry_t backtrace[..];


#define FUNC_EXIT(error_code__) \
do { \
  backtrace[func_id].code = (error_code__); \
  backtrace[func_id].error_name = #error_code__; \
} while (0)
```

Then, when you call `FUNC_EXIT(E_SUCCESS);`, you'll get for the backtrace for the function to be: `{.code = 0, .error_name = "E_SUCCESS"}`

The problem is, you can't get the right name if you call `FUNC_EXIT(var);`, where `var` is some local variable.

---

Another option, although still not an automagical one:

```c
typedef enum
{
  E_SUCCESS = 0,
  E_FAIL,
...
  NOF_ERROR_CODES
} error_t;

#define MAP_E_CODE_TO_NAME(error_code__)  [error_code__] = #error_code__

const char * error_to_name_mapping[NOF_ERROR_CODES] = {
  MAP_E_CODE_TO_NAME(E_SUCCESS),
  MAP_E_CODE_TO_NAME(E_FAIL),
...
};
```

Will give a `const char *` array with `{"E_SUCCESS", "E_FAIL", ...}`, which you can use like this:

```c
printf("The name of error code %d is '%s'", error, error_to_name_mapping[error]);
```

The problem here is that you have to have positive value to errors with increasing values.

Comment: Thanks. I should've specify it probably, but I can't save all these error strings as part of the output binary (embedded constraints). That's why I'm after "static analysis" solution.

Comment: You can compile the static mapping separately on a PC and #ifdef it out on your embedded target..

Comment: And then how will I be able to analyze the `backtrace` of embedded runs? I can't always reproduce the same run for embedded system on PC.

Comment: I meant share the error codes between a PC C application that only analizes the backtrace and your embedded application. One compilation would generate the embedded target with some error code enum, and one compilation will create a PC application that analizes backtrace. The main thing is that the errors are defined only once between the applications.

Comment: The PC C program may also only generate a dictionary for other tools of your choice, written in python/perl/ruby/...

Comment: To my understanding, in order to create that dictionary I'll need to call a macro for every enum definition, which is what I'm trying to save / automate.